# GAE persisted value not updating in deployed app but locally

Tags: java, google-app-engine, persistence, jdo

Currently I'm working on a small project which involves GAE using JDO, however I seem to have a problem persisting the updated data - the strange thing is it works locally but not in the deployed version of the app.
The update is pretty straightforward:

```
update(Foo newBar) {
    PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
    Transaction trans = pm.currentTransaction();
    trans.begin();
    Foo bar = pm.getObjectById(Foo.class, "someId");
    bar.baz = newBar.baz;
    pm.makePersistent(bar);
    trans.commit();
    pm.close();
}
```

Is there anything I'm missing here?

Comment: how does it not work?

Comment: The first time 'bar' is being made persistent but the value it has, remains the same for every consecutive call.
However executed locally, 'bar' is updated and persisted properly on every call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating a public field directly ? Oh dear. No persistence mechanism has a hope of knowing that you updated that field if you do it that way. Use a setter, or enhance the updating class as @PersistenceAware.

Inspection of the log would reveal many things, like that call to makePersistent is of no value

Comment: Inspecting the log was not revealing any problems, as I said it works locally and the object is marked as dirty and the call to makePersistent works as expected..
But using a setter did the trick. Thanks a lot!! I should probably find out how the persistence mechanism of DataNucleus works...

Just out of curiosity do you have any idea what else could be the reason why there was the discrepancy between the local and the deployed behaviour?